# Press the button 5 times to end the process and output the result

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a typing game in JavaScript. I'm doing an assignment, and I've finished processing 1 and 2. but I don't understand the issues of 3 and 4. When I read the article on the net, but I couldn't achieve it with my tech.

1. The user sees the subject text, types the same value into the text box, and presses the OK button.
2. When the OK button is pressed, clear the text box and display the next subject.
3. Repeat steps 1 and 2 5 times.
4. When the ok button is pressed the 5th time, the total number of characters from the 1st to the 5th times, in which the theme and the value entered by the user are incorrect, is displayed on the screen.

Comment: Are you testing that they put the right word in or type the right keys?

Comment: yes.I've tested it many times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than the mispelling mentioned, you are counting correct answers twice, it should be counted only in the `keypress evenListener` (it's also being counted in the `check()` function which makes it double

Then add in the end of the `check()` function:

```
if (CorrectCount >= 5) {
        finish();
    }
```

This will make the game stop after 5 OK's as intended.

Answer (score 0):

In the check function, you misspelled the variable name. `uestionList` should be `questionList`